# How to load tensorflow checkponit by myself without c++ api?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am using tensorflow 1.0.

My production environment cannot build tensorflow-cpp because low gcc&glibc version.

Is there any doc about how to load a checkponit or freezed-graph in C++ **without api**?

1、 how to save network parameter? (embeding...)

2、 how to save graph structure (layers,weights...)

Comment: by  __without api__ you mean the python wrapper?

Comment: @putonspectacles  I means dump the weight in csv format and graph structure in protobuf of json format . so that I can parse in production and do inference myself :  do some matmul,relu ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation on doing this that I know of. Loading a checkpoint without the C++ runtime won't be very useful to you because you won't be able to run it.

The checkpoint by default does not include the graph structure, but if you export a metagraph you will get it in a serialized protocol buffer format. Implementing a parser for this (and the weights checkpoint) yourself sounds difficult to get right and likely to break in the future.